# Codeigniter Integration Facebook API PHP SDK 3

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, integration

Is there any elegant way to integrate Facebook PHP API into codeigniter so with **one codeigniter installation to manage multiply Facebook apps**?

Comment: updated blog to show how to use the official php-sdk with codeigniter ... http://jondavidjohn.com/b/P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This short article is more actual for me:
http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/07/using-the-facebook-api-with-codeigniter

Nothing superfluous - just the usage of Facebook official PHP Class with CI.

Answer (score 7):

Go for:

- [Facebook API: php-sdk using Codeigniter](http://brandonbeasley.com/blog/facebook-api-codeigniter/)

Other Useful Resources::

- [Getting CodeIgniter to play nicely with Facebook](http://wishli.st/blog/getting-codeigniter-to-play-nicely-with-facebook/)
- [Facebook & CodeIgniter – Definitive Guide](http://www.simpleprojectz.com/2008/10/facebook-codeigniter/)
- [A sample Facebook application with CodeIgniter.](http://junal.wordpress.com/2008/01/20/a-sample-facebook-application-with-codeigniter/)

Comment: this are for old codeignter versions do you think i may have any problem or not ? thanks !

Comment: the first 3 links are broken

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a simple library that you can just drop in to your codeIgniter libraries.
I've used it in a couple of production sites and it's pretty stable. I am now working on adding commonly used features to the library to make working with facebook seamless and easy.

https://github.com/bugzbrown/codeigniter-facebook-lib

Answer (score 1):

One more sample link:
https://github.com/elliothaughin/codeigniter-facebook